Proof of: Connected graph with three distinct adjacency matrix eigenvalues with the largest eigenvalue nonintegral is complete bipartite.
In the paper "Graphs with Three Eigenvalues" by E. R. van Dam, proposition 2 says that if a connected graph has three distinct eigenvalues and the largest is nonintegral, then it's a complete bipartite graph.  I have a question about one part of the proof.
We assume the largest eigenvalue is nonintegral.  We know the largest eigenvalue has multiplicity one by Perron-Frobenius.  The author claims that at least one of the other eigenvalues is also nonintegral with multiplicity one.  The part about nonintegral is easy to see, since the eigenvalues must sum to zero.  However, I do not understand why the other nonintegral eigenvalue must have multiplicity one.

An attempt is needed here; as is we have no clue what you consider background knowledge.  For an $n\times n$ matrix, you should be able to solve this from scratch for $n\in \big{3,4,5\big}$.  A little cleverness is needed to get the $n\geq 6$ case.

It's because the characteristic polynomial of the adjacency matrix of a graph has rational coefficients.  Therefore, the multiset of eigenvalues is closed under Galois conjugation.
